# Convert table row into array in python with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to convert a table row to an array using numpy in Python.
Example:

```
table_attributes.row(3)
Row(Hemoglobin=0.5961076648232668, Glucose=-0.19065363034327712)

np.array(table_attributes.row(3))
```

The error that I get:

```
tuple.index(x): x not in tuple
```

Can you help me make the conversion work? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what is the Row class? What package is it from? Is it from `pyspark.sql.Row` ?

Comment: Its not from pyspark.sql.  I don't know more than that.